# Using the same value to replace all placeholders in a printf format string

Tags: bash, printf

I feel that there should be a more efficient way to accomplish what I am trying to do, but after a while of trying to find a better way, I can't figure it out.

`printf "%s=( \"%s_actions\" \"%s_items\" \"%s_people\" \"%s_rooms\" )\n" "$REPLY" "$REPLY" "$REPLY" "$REPLY" "$REPLY"`

There must be a better way to get this done, but I can't figure out. All I'm tying to do is print the text within the outside quotes, replacing every %s with the same variable.

I know this is probably pretty stupid, but what can I do?

Comment: It feels like you want to generate bash code, in which case it's required to check the content of `$REPLY`, for ex. with something like `[[ $REPLY =~ ^[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*$ ]] || exit 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `printf` to evaluate a format string at all here: Parameter expansion will do. `${var//PATTERN/REPLACEMENT}` replaces all instances of `PATTERN` with `REPLACEMENT`, so...

```
REPLY=hi
var='%s=( \"%s_actions\" \"%s_items\" \"%s_people\" \"%s_rooms\" )'
result="${var//%s/"$REPLY"}"
```

...will assign `hi=( "hi_actions" "hi_items" "hi_people" "hi_rooms" )` to `result`.

Comment: I knew I was an idiot and was just missing something simple. I always forget about that replacement. Thanks!

Comment: `printf '%s=( "%s_actns" "%s_items" "%s_people" "%s_rooms" )\n' "$REPLY"{,,,,}`